# What profiler to use with sql express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

is there a way to monitor detail of sql calls in express version?

Comment: Sadly per all the answers for the free SQL express profiler, it appears to be no longer free, even the open source is "gone". Shoulda archived a copy when I had it. Now's it's a commercial product w/ free trial.

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28213/download-sql-server-profiler-for-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try [SQL Express Profiler](http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com).

I've used it a bit and it seems to work as advertised.

Comment: I'm looking for this now! The asker asked 3 years ago! So, when the answer provider found that and work on that! World is really ahead-ed, I'm really in behind, please you all help me to go upward, Thanks.

Comment: does this work for SQL server 2016?

Comment: http://www.completelyuninstallprogram.com/sqlexpressprofiler-exe/ say this is trojan. Chrome browser also complain this setup is malicious. Is anything wrong with SQL Express Profiler?

Answer (score 5):

As most of the profilers mentioned above seem to be dead or gone commercial, I would like to share what I found some days ago:

[SQL Express Profiler](https://github.com/OleksiiKovalov/expressprofiler)

Since CodePlex has been retired, the project moved to GitHub and seems to have no binary download options anymore, so you have to compile it from source code.

I'm currently using it with SQL Server Express 2012 to monitor queries form my NHibernate applications (didn't want to add log4net just for this purpose and show_sql outputs only to console window which I don't have in my WCF service).

Really nice and stable utility. I find it much easier to use than MS SQL Profiler which needs various settings, trace profiles for various server versions and what not. Express Profiler - just launch, hit Run, and all the T-SQL and sp_execute queries are displayed.

It's open source, you can add even more features if you wish. I guess, Clear button would be useful because now you have to Stop and Run again to clear the list.

Comment: Oh, this post was edited by someone to replace the free profiler link with the paid one... I guess they have their reasons to do that, but now you'll have to google for express profiler on codeplex.

Comment: I've fixed this, @martin - I'm guessing you also wanted to link to express profiler, though if it is some other link you wanted to point to, then please fix it (or mention in comments so one of us can fix it).

Comment: Thanks @Roopesh, now it is the right one.

Comment: Looks like it is gone now...

Comment: @JayKilleen You can still download the source code and compile it, both from CodePlex archive and also the new GitHub repository.

Comment: Cheers I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned [SqlProfiler For Express Edition](http://www.DataWizard.com/) works fine for development.

But I have not found it always useful in solving production emergencies, like when sqlexpress takes 100% of server processor capacity. I couldn't get the profiler produce any trace in one such case. Perhaps there are similar experiences?

Answer (score 2):

Express edition is just the full version with some limitations (2GB ram, 2 cpu cores, 4GB DB), so if you have the tools for the full version, use them. I think the trial version off the MS website will allow you to use the tools - but not the engine - for more than 60 days..... tho there may be an official package of the tools around for express

Answer (score 2):

I have been using AnjLab Sql Profiler for quite some time. I have had no problems with it.

**Edit:**
Here is the link: http://anjlab.com/en/projects/opensource/sqlprofiler

Answer (score 1):

The free SQL profiler others mention appears no longer available. Next best alternative might be something like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20173/MS-SQL-Server-Profiler-with-NET

Answer (score 1):

You could rather use SQL Server Extended Events instead of any Profiler.
Extended Events are available from within the Express version. There is UI management from SQL Server 2012 under the Management folder of a server in the Object Explorer window.

You can read a good answer on the advantages of using Extended Events over SQL Profiler -which include less performance overhead- at Stack Exchange:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2665/when-should-extended-events-be-used-instead-of-sql-profiler-perfmon

"Extended Events is the future of monitoring & troubleshooting going forward and some day in the future SQL Trace will be removed"

Regards.

Comment: Not everyone likes to write queries. Even with today's command line approach on the rise (sublime, npm, anyone?), I prefer UI.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer we can buy SQL Server 2005/08 Developer Edition which is available for $50 or so. It has full featured SQL Profiler and works beyond SQL Server Express SKUs limitations.

If not than use [SQL Express Profiler](http://www.DataWizard.com)

Hope this helps!