# Are stored procedures executed from text string?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, request, binary-data, plaintext

There are several SQL servers having stored procedures, for example Microsoft SQL Server or PostgreSQL. There are also several client side objects implementing stored procedures calls (`TADOStoredProc` in Delphi, `SqlCommand` in .NET Framework etc.).

The question I always wanted to ask is:

are stored procedures executed always in special efficient way with binary representation of their parameters or are the super-advanced objects which represent stored procedures' parameters always converted to a plain text string and stored procedure is always executed by sending this plain text string to SQL server? (Let's take one technology for example - let it be SQL Server and ADO.NET).

I noticed that for ADO.NET procedure's parameter names do not have any meaning - only their creation order is important which makes me think about an idea with plain text string.

**Update for @Alex K.**

I've tested following code in .NET:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE paramtest
@par1 nvarchar(50),
@par2 nvarchar(50),
@par3 nvarchar(50)
AS
  SELECT Res = '@par1 = ' + @par1 + '; @par2 = ' + @par2 + '; @par3 = ' + @par3
  RETURN 555
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace SqlParamTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void addParam(SqlCommand cmd, string parameterName, ParameterDirection direction, SqlDbType dbType, int size, object value)
        {
            SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter(parameterName, dbType, size);
            par.Direction = direction;
            par.Value = value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "paramtest";
                addParam(cmd, "@par3", ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "third");
                addParam(cmd, "@par2", ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "second");
                addParam(cmd, "@par1", ParameterDirection.Input, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "first");
                addParam(cmd, "@Return", ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, SqlDbType.Int, 0, null);
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                if (rdr.Read()) Console.WriteLine((string)rdr["Res"]);
                rdr.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Return value: {0}", cmd.Parameters["@Return"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

and yes, it maintains parameters in a right way, but I think, it is .NET who adds additional checks to parameters, because following code in Delphi:

```
procedure TMyClass.Test(Conn: TADOConnection);
var SP:TADOStoredProc;
begin
  SP := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
  try
    SP.Connection := Conn;
    SP.ProcedureName := 'paramtest';
    SP.Parameters.CreateParameter('@whatthehell', ftString, pdInput, 50, 'one');
    SP.Parameters.CreateParameter('@AnotherCrap', ftString, pdInput, 50, 'two');
    SP.Parameters.CreateParameter('?', ftString, pdInput, 50, 'three');
    SP.ExecProc;
  finally
    SP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

returns:

```
@par1 = one; @par2 = two; @par3 = three
```

and doesn't complain about missing parameters.

pdReturnValue works only if this parameter is created before any other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what answer your looking for, stored procedure command text & parameters are passed to the driver/provider or natively via ADO.NET which formats it as a TDS (tabular data stream) RPC (remote procedure call) Message which is then passed to the server over which ever network protocol is being used; pipes, tcp/ip et al.  The data is sent in a binary stream.

The TDS spec [is available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx) from Microsoft if your interested.

`SQLCommand` Stored Procedure calls do need a parameter name, its OleDB/ODBC that only care about the order and use `?` as the parameter placeholder rather than `@NAME`.

**Regarding order**

In your example the order is not relevant because you are providing the server with the correct names for the params, so this is what is sent to the server:

```
exec paramtest @par3=N'third',@par2=N'second',@par1=N'first'
```

This is enough information for the server to figure out the correct params/order.

If you changed to

```
addParam(cmd, "@xxpar3",
addParam(cmd, "@xxpar2", 
addParam(cmd, "@xxpar1",
```

The server would detect that it does not have a param named `xxxpar*` and fail with a "missing @par1" error.

If you modified `addParam` so it did not set paramater names .net will create defaults:

```
exec paramtest @Parameter1=N'third',@Parameter2=N'second',@Parameter3=N'first'
```

Which would cause the above error.

If you modified `addParam` so it did not set paramater names and then overwrite the automatic ones;

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(par);
par.ParameterName = "";
```

This is what gets executed:

```
 exec paramtest N'third',N'second',N'first'
```

resulting in

```
 @par1 = third; @par2 = second; @par3 = first
```

I have no idea what Delphi does ... The full version of SQL Server ships with a tool called SQL Profiler which displays the textual data that gets sent to the server instance so you can see exactly whats going on.
[What profiler to use with sql express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616388/what-profiler-to-use-with-sql-express)